# can't scroll UITableView - objective C xCode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, scroll

I have a UITableView inside my View Controller and the data loads into the table but I can't scroll through it at all.  I've tried many ways to fix it but can't find a solution. I also have use SWRevealViewController for a sidebar menu but I don't think that would effect the scrolling capabilities?

Here's the code inside my View Controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
if ( revealViewController )
{
    [self.barButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
    [self.barButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}

_providerName = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                 @"Food Bank of Alaska",
                 @"Community Food Bank of Central Alabama",
                 @"Food Bank of North Alabama",
                 @"Montgomery Area Food Bank",
                 @"Feeding the Gulf Coast",
                 @"Northwest Arkansas Food Bank",
                 @"River Valley Regional Food Bank",
                 @"Food Bank of Northeast Arkansas",
                 @"Arkansas Foodbank",
                 @"Harvest Texarkana Regional Food Bank",
                 @"United Food Bank",
                 @"St. Mary's Food Bank Alliance",
                 ... (there's more data here)
                 nil];
_providerId = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", @"0", @"0", 
                                               @"0", @"0", @"0",
                                               @"0", @"0", @"0", 
                                         ..... (there's more data here) 
                                               nil];


      self.navigationItem.title = @"Call History";
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    // Remove seperator inset
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
     }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
     if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)])       {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }
    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.providerName count];
 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"moneyItemRow";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.textLabel.text = [self.providerName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.detailTextLabel.text =[self.providerId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     return cell;

 }
```

Here's a picture of my view controller to show that the table view isnt near any of the edges so nothing is overlapping it

[image: Description]

Comment: user interaction is enabled for your table view?

Comment: I added that to my code but it's still not working

Comment: Do you have any other scrollview in your view hierarchy? Please share the view hierarchy too.

Comment: What segue is it to the NavigationController? (Maybe it is in a containerView)

Comment: What's the constraints/frame setting of your `UITableView`?

Comment: check in preview if any layer is above your table view. @JohnHenry

Comment: Under constraints it says... Trailing Space to: Superview    Equals: -5.00000            Leading Space to: Superview         Bottom Space to: Superview    Equals: Default          Top Space to: Top Layout...   Equals: 21

Answer (score 0):

//remove this code

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
// Remove seperator inset
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
 }

// Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
 if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)])       {
    [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
}
// Explictly set your cell's layout margins
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the full answer of table view scroll